# How to use unpack-dependencies but not fail when a dependency can't be found?

Tags: maven

I would like to use `mvn dependency:unpack-dependencies -Dclassifier=sources` on my project so I can use ctags on the dependencies' sources.  However, if a dependency doesn't have any sources, this command fails.

```
 org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin:2.1:unpack-dependencies (default-cli) on project X: not found in any repository: Y
```

It seems that `-DfailOnMissingClassifierArtifact` was meant to avoid this failure, but it doesn't seem to affect anything.  Is there a way I can download just the available sources?  I am not interested in manually omitting artifactIds.

Comment: Did you set `-DfailOnMissingClassifierArtifact=false` ? It is true by default.

Comment: Yes, apologies if I didn't make this clear in my question.  I thought this flag would fix the problem, but it didn't change anything.

Comment: Added an answer after trying this out myself:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A second reading of the [documentation](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/unpack-dependencies-mojo.html#failOnMissingClassifierArtifact) revealed the correct variable to be used.

```
-Dmdep.failOnMissingClassifierArtifact=false
```

Comment: Ah, good call.  I'll have to remember that the expression can differ from the title.